# Не могу разобраться с VK_api?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Вообщем пытаюсь создать бота для ВК на python'е, в языке я новичок.
Проблема в том что не могу сделать что бы бот присылал сообщение в чат, в ЛС с ботом все хорошо, а вот в чате не работает.

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from datetime import datetime
import random
import data

token = "***"

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)
vk = vk.get_api()

while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            print('сообщение пришло в ' + str(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%H:%M:%S')))
            print('текс ' + str(event.text))
            # print(event.chat_id)
            a = event.text.lower()
            if event.peer_id and not event.chat_id:
                if a == 'привет':
                    vk.messages.send(peer_id = event.peer_id , message='Hello world', random_id=0)
```

Comment: Боту выдано право читать сообщения в чате? По умолчанию боты не могут читать сообщения в чатах, администратор должен назначить им это право (так же, как обычным пользователям назначаются права администратора)

Comment: у бота в чате есть права администратора

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас указана старая версия API в настройках long poll API. Установите версию >=5.80
[image: настройки которые должны быть]
Так же убедитесь, что у вас включены все необходимые для бота типы событий

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
UPD: За одно рекомендую ознакомиться с примерами использования API [VK_API](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/tree/master/examples)

Comment: не как не получается

Comment: @Link_Z в коде попробуйте изменить `if event.peer_id and not event.chat_id:` на `if event.peer_id and event.chat_id:`